# multiple scanf program but one scanf is skipped, what is the reason?

Tags: c, scanf

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{   
     float x1, x2, y1, y2, dis;
     printf("enter the pair of points in (x1,x2) format (example: (2,3)): ");
     scanf("(%f,%f)", &x1, &y1);

     printf("enter the pair of points in (x1,x2) format (example: (2,3)): ");
     scanf("(%f,%f)", &x2, &y2);

     dis = sqrt( pow(x1 - x2, 2) + pow(y1 - y2, 2) );
     printf("\n the distance between the points is : %f",dis);

     return 0;
}
```

the program has the first `scanf` reading the input fine but the second gets skipped, I used devc++ compiler here. what is the reason for the skipping of the second `scanf`?

Comment: What is your input? Does it separate the two values with a comma as the format string requires? The `scanf`function has a return value, namely the number of converted itams. Use it.

Comment: Try: `scanf(" (%f,%f)",&x2,&y2);`. That is, add a space as the first character in the string. Because the previous `scanf` leaves a newline character which does not match `(`. The space in the string will cause `scanf` to skip all white spaces. Also, it is always best practice to check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @MOehm Yes , my input is to be as required by the  format string, under that circumstance the scanf() is skipped

Comment: @kaylum Thank you , I have tried as you asked and it works. Can you explain the part "leaves a newline character which does not match ("?

Comment: I commented because I wanted you to include the input you gave in the question. The `scanf` function looks simple, but has a lot of potential pitfalls. Do yourself a favour and check the result of `scanf` so that you know that it succeeded. Stuff outside the conversion formats (`%` something) must be matched verbatim except white space, which can be matched by any amount of whitespace, including none. And, somewhat unintuitively, `scanf` treats a new line like any other white space.

Comment: @JatinRai What kaylum is saying is simply that the string `"(1.0,1.0)\n(1.0,1.0)\n"`  Does not match the format string `"(%f,%f)(%f,%f)"` because of the newline.  By inserting whitespace, you match the newline.